# How do I put a space in my electron app's title?

Tags: windows-10, electron, export, package.json, macos-catalina

First off I obviously know how to rename the app after I export it, but I want to have it export with the correct name the first time. How do I put a space in the name of it? Here is the relevant portion of the package.json code:

```
"name": "Calculator",
  "build": {
    "appId": "Calculator.id",
    "mac": {
      "icon": "img/calculatoricon.png",
      "target": []
    },
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A month late reply but I also encountered a similar issue.
You can use *productName* key for it.

```json
{
  "name": "calculator",
  "productName": "Calculator with Spaces",
  "build": {
    "appId": "calculator.id",
    "mac": {
      "icon": "img/calculator_icon.png",
      "target": []
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the reference:
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetname

Comment: Thanks. i figured it out literally a day before you posted this.